# Connecting BM800 condenser to PC

Tags: microphone

I'm very new to the subject of recording to PC .  I intend to begin simply by making recordings for some YouTube videos.  I didn't wish to spend a great deal in case I give up and am not too bothered about very high quality.

I bought a BM800 condenser microphone together with a simple Neewer phantom power supply.  I have an Asus Donar XG sound card with a 3.5mm jack socket in my PC.  I connected as I thought correctly i.e. Mic to Neewer input and then Neewer output to 3.5 mm jack. I have set up the mic in recording devices on the PC and the level is at 100% but no input from the Mic.

I have tried using Audacity and set the input device as Mic on sound card but nothing.  I tried connecting the mic directly to the sound card as I heard that it should work when directly connected to a sound card and fiddled with all the settings but again nothing.

Have I done something wrong? Do I need to connect to a USB port with a suitable XLR to USB cable from the PSU?  Is the mic a dud? Is there a way of verifying the working of the mic other than connecting it correctly?  I am a bit flummoxed and would be grateful for any help from you experts>

Best regards

Terry

Comment: If you have a friend's machine to test, that would be the easiest

Comment: Hi, this would be my best solution but I'm afraid I'm on  my own in this, no one I know is involved in this sort of stuff.

Comment: Almost all pcs have audio hardware that will be sufficient for you to test with

Answer (score 1):

Condenser microphones need power to work with.

Three possible solutions:

- an XLR to USB cable, connect XLR side to mic, and USB side to PC
- Audio interface such as Behringer, or Focusrite
- Use a USB soundcard (not suggested)